# i can't define the variable to update my database

Tags: php

this is the code :

```
<?php
include "../include/koneksi_db.php";
include "../user/link.php";     
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id=$id", $konek);
$hasil=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$id  =$hasil['id'];
$user=$hasil['username'];
$pass=$hasil['password'];
$hak =$hasil['hak_akses'];
?>
```

Question:
 How to fix this : Nocticce: Undefined Variable: id in C:....\ed_user.php on line 5

Comment: `$id = 5; mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id=$id")` Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: What is your question? What is not working?

Comment: You guys be gentle with the downvotes, the OP is clearly a kid with little english knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly : This ?

```
<?php
include "../include/koneksi_db.php";
include "../user/link.php";

 $check_the_query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='".$id."'";
$query=mysql_query(, $konek);

while($hasil=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $id  =$hasil['id'];
    $user=$hasil['username'];
    $pass=$hasil['password'];
    $hak =$hasil['hak_akses'];

    echo "id -> ".$id."<br>";
    echo "user -> ".$id."<br>";
    echo("<br>");
}

?>
```